# How to build gcc-6.3 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, gcc, mex, configure

I've been struggling with building gcc-6.3 from source on Ubuntu 18.04 as gcc-6.3 is the current supported gcc in mex for Matlab. I downloaded the source and configure the make in various ways such as disabling a few options that would circumvent the build but without success. Do you know any way to make this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I probably get punished for suggesting this dirty solution but it worked for me:

Download gcc-6.4 from the official Ubuntu repository and change every
occurrence of 6.4 to 6.3 in /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-6